# Rails API ActiveStorage DirectUpload produce 422 Error InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-activestorage

I have a problem with Rails API app active storage. I have React from where i want to upload file.

```
import React from "react";
import {DirectUpload} from "activestorage";

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: null
    };
    this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFileSubmit = this.handleFileSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleFileChange(e){
    this.setState({file: e.target.files[0]})
  }

  handleFileSubmit(){
    const upload = new DirectUpload(this.state.file, "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads");

    upload.create((error, blob) => {
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log(blob)
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Form>
          <Form.Item>
            <Input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange}/>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Register
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

But on submit i got error `Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-09 22:59:54 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"file.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>27095, "checksum"=>"8u95dXg39vap1Cq/2fgfbg=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"file.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>27095, "checksum"=>"8u95dXg39vap1Cq/2fgfbg=="}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:211:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:243:in `handle_unverified_request'
devise (4.6.2) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:238:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
```

I set in application_controller.rb `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` but i still got error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Two ways to solve this :

#### 1. Monkey patch (Not recommended)

in `config/initializers/direct_uploads.rb` :

```
require 'active_storage/direct_uploads_controller'

class ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

#### 2. Custom controller (recommended)

Let's say you have and API endpoint to `/api/v1` :

`config/routes.rb`

```
namespace :api do
  scope module: 'v1', path: 'v1' do
    resources :direct_uploads, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

---

`app/controllers/api/v1/direct_uploads_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::DirectUploadsController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController
  # Should only allow null_session in API context, so request is JSON format
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  # Also, since authenticity verification by cookie is disabled, you should implement you own logic :
  before_action :verify_user

  private

  def verify_user
    raise unless User.find(doorkeeper_token[:resource_owner_id])
  end
end
```

And change the DirectUpload instanciation with the right endpoint :

```
const upload = new DirectUpload(this.state.file, "/api/v1/direct_uploads");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7 (but could have been introduced before) the documentation accessible [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) mentions the following:

```
// your form needs the file_field direct_upload: true, which 
//  provides data-direct-upload-url, data-direct-upload-token 
// and data-direct-upload-attachment-name
```

Here is the inside of one of my stimulus controller as an example (should work the same with minor adaptions with React):

```
addFile(event) {
  const files = event.target.files;
  Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file);
      const url = event.target.dataset.directUploadUrl;
      const token = event.target.dataset.directUploadToken;
      const attachmentName = event.target.dataset.directUploadAttachmentName;
      console.log(`attachmentName: ${attachmentName}`);
      const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url, token, attachmentName);

      upload.create((error, blob) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return;
        } else {
          // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE UPLOADED IMAGE
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom controller with `skip_forgery_protection` to disable forgery protection on API only mode.

```rb
# app/controllers/api/v1/direct_uploads_controller.rb
class Api::V1::DirectUploadsController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController
  skip_forgery_protection
end
```