# Error http 422 with DirectUpload / ActiveStorage / Rails

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I try to add some images with ajax via DirectUpload / ActiveStorage / Rails 6.
I use the prerequisites into of ActiveStorage support, for use DirectUpload with Jquery :
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#integrating-with-libraries-or-frameworks

```
const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url)

  upload.create((error, blob) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle the error
    } else {
      // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form with a
      [..]
      console.log(blob.key);
    }
  })
```

On my host, it works for all files. But when I try to publish my app into my hoster, I have an error for some files, always the same, after the request of DirectUpload :

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 689)
```

I looked the XHR requests into my webtools browser, but the payload seems the same into a file which works and another which fails :

```
{id: 219, key: "v2v1aqlk8gyygcc4smjeh0bbuc59", filename: "groupama logo.jpeg",…}
id: 219
key: "v2v1aqlk8gyygcc4smjeh0bbuc59" 
filename: "logo.jpeg" 
content_type: "image/jpeg" 
metadata: {}
byte_size: 17805
checksum: "3GIVi2kNKClfH+d9HGYOfkA==" 
created_at: "2020-04-09T08:25:40.000+02:00" 
signed_id: "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2zaFnZSI6IkJBaHBBZHM9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--7c0750cb8c86a955a04fa9a11dc5389cdeb5e7b0" 
attachable_sgid: "BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIxsaZ2lkOi8vYXBwL0FjdGl2ZVN0b3JhZ2U6OkJsb2IvMjE5P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIg9hdHRhY2hhYmxlBjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--64a945c38dc5d85c05156da50b9c38819b106e10" 
direct_upload: {,…}
url: "http://localhost:8491/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkakoyTVdGeGJHczRaM2w1WjJOak5ITnRhbVZvTUdKaWRXTTFPUVk2QmtWVU9oRmpiMjaUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWRG9UWTI5dWRHVnVkRjlzWlc1bmRHaHBBbzFGT2cxamFHVmphM04xYlVraUhUTkhTVlpwTW10T1MwTnNaa2dyT1VoSFdVOW1hMEU5UFFZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA0LTA5VDA2OjMwOjQwLjg5NFoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX3Rva2VuIn19--a2acedc0924f735c5cc08db8c4b76f76accc3c8d" 
headers: {Content-Type: "image/jpeg"}
```

I tried this solution, by the monkey patch doesn't works for me, and another solution seems not working :
[Rails API ActiveStorage DirectUpload produce 422 Error InvalidAuthenticityToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067616/rails-api-activestorage-directupload-produce-422-error-invalidauthenticitytoken)

I noticed, when I try to upload the logo image file without use DirectUpdate into input file, the file is correctly well send to my server.

```
= f.file_field :logos, direct_upload: true
```

Do you have any idea to test ?

Comment: In fact, the problem seems to come about the size of the images when I try to upload via DirectUpload in ajax.  Once the size image make more of 18ko, there is an error to upload. I have the same error, when I use ActiveText, and I try to past a new image.

Comment: My hoster use uwsgi and rack for deliver ror website.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was coming with the IO which was use for copy the file. Into the `ActiveStorage::DiskController#update`, Rails use the `request.body` and `IO.CopyStream` for create the file, and a checksum file was done for verifiy the file created.
And the check fail and throw the 422 http error.

I noticed than the IO stream, in dev mode was a `String_IO`, whereas on my hoster, the IO was a `Uswgi_IO`. Because my hoster deliver the ruby on rails application with Uswgi.
The uwsgi_io not contains a length or size methods, and when ActiveStorage create the file with this IO, the size of file was weird. Weirdly too large.

I noticed if the `RAW_POST_DATA` was assign, then the `request.body` return a `String_IO`. And into the `request.raw_post` method, the body was read directly with the `request.content_length` :

```
raw_post_body.read(content_length)
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-body

I created a new controller which inherits of `ActiveStorage::DiskController`, in order to assign the `RAW_POST_DATA`, before the `Disk#update` action.

```
class UploadController < ActiveStorage::DiskController

  def update
    request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = request.body.read(request.content_length)    
    super
  end
end
```

And after, I override the ActiveStorage disk#update route by mine :

```
put '/rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token', to: 'upload#update
```

And it works !

ActionText works with ActiveStorage for store the images, and I had the same issue with the images too large.
My patch allows to make works ActionText on my hoster too.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for finding the culprit here, I was having the exact same issue on a uwsgi setup and I was trying to figure out why the content length was different when I found your post. Thanks for sharing !

I just took a slightly different approach with the fix as I didn't want to hack the AS routes, so I created a config/initializers file with the following code :

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::DiskController.class_eval do
    before_action :set_raw_post_data, only: :update

    def set_raw_post_data
      request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = request.body.read(request.content_length)
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe it would be worth creating an issue in https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi to let them know about this ?